# How to infer a generic type in kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin, generics

I've done this code and don't uderstand what could be wrong :

```
   fun <T : ComplicationDataSourceService> getCorrespondingComplicationService(): Class<T>? {
        return when (this) {
            IMMOBILITY -> ImmobilityComplicationService::class.java
            HEART_RATE -> null
            POWER_BUTTON -> null
            SHORTCUT -> null
        }
    }
```

```
class ImmobilityComplicationService: ComplicationDataSourceService() {
    ...
}
```

I got this compilation error :
Type mismatch, required:
Class<T>?
Found:
Class<ImmobilityComplicationService>

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function signature claims that the *caller* can choose a T, and it'll return a `Class<T>` for that T, no matter what it is.

That's not true.  Your function returns a `Class` for *some* subclass of `ComplicationDataSourceService`, but the caller doesn't pick that type.

Instead, the correct type of your function is

```
fun getCorrespondingComplicationService(): Class<out ComplicationDataSourceService>?
```